# How to find out what is installed on a server

Tags: unix

I'm an undergrad student and we have special access to a server. The server is a unix server (don't know the OS or anything.. is there a way to find out? ).

we also get a website associated with the server. There is a public_html folder. I uploaded with a test file with phpinfo() but the server didnt parse it (yes i had the right extension) . So im guessing PHP isn't installed. is there a way to see what "common" languages ARE installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to figure out what OS is installed. It's likely that this may be displayed when you first ssh into the box. If not, running `$ uname -a` will most likely give you some clues. If you determine it's running linux, you'll need to find out what packages have been installed. If it's an rpm-based distro (RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, etc.), then `$ rpm -qa` will display all of the installed packages. If it's a debian-based distro (Debian, Ubuntu, etc.), then `$ dpkg --get-selections` will give you the list of all installed packages. If you determine that, at some point, packages have been installed outside of the package management system (from source, via tarball), then you're pretty much stuck to crawling the filesystem to see what binaries are around - not a pretty task.

If you determine it's not linux, then I probably won't be of much help.

Comment: well, when i putty/telnet in the address is unix.aml.yorku.ca haha but i'll double check in a sec and reply back.

edit: uname -a returned "AIX unix 3 *bunch of numbers*"

Comment: Well in that case, it looks like you have an AIX box. AIX is a unix variant that IBM sells. I have worked very briefly on a couple of AIX boxes in my day, but I certainly don't know enough to help you figure out what packages have been installed. Hopefully a more experienced AIX admin will chime in. In the meantime, the following pages looks like it has some information that may be helpful to you: http://www.coolcommands.com/index.php?option=com_cccat&task=display&id=235

Comment: Also, just by doing a bit of research on the system you mentioned - it's likely that you're not the administrator of this machine, correct? If so, an easier route to figuring things out may be to just contact the IT support org that oversees AML and see if they have any documentation to help get you started. That will likely be much faster than poking around tirelessly for hours.